# Run two applications on the same domain in Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy, vps

I have an AWS VPS where a React app runs on a reverse proxy Nginx+Domain and SSL, in this same VPS I have a NodeJS API which is the backend of the application running on another port.
I would like to know how do I integrate the App with the API on the server with the same domain. The app is running on port 3000 and the api on port 3001.
Do I need to open both ports for the same domain in Nginx? Or create a subdomain in the application's domain and redirect requests to the url meuapp.com/api to the other Node service on port 3001?

That is, what is the best way to run an app on one port and an api on another in the same VPS/Proxy/Domain structure and still make the api accessible to other applications?

Answer (score 0):

--- Updated Answer

If you want to use **subpath approach**, you should be able to achieve this with a Nginx configuration as follows:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  listen  [::]:80;
  server_name  meuapp.com;
  
  location / {
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    rewrite             /api/(.*) /$1  break;
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
  }
}
```

--- Original Answer

I would probably go for the **subdomain approach**. Says, you can have a domain `api.meuapp.com` for API and a domain `www.meuapp.com` for frontend.

The idea would be like this:

[image]

If you use the subdomain approach, please bear in mind you will need to set up CORS accordingly.

Comment: I have only one domain, let's say, meuapp.com where the app runs, I wanted to know, if there is a way, and, if so, how to configure Nginx to receive requests for the api in that same domain/sub, something like meuapp.com/api and redirect them to the backend.
I think this must be a simple configuration in Nginx, but everything I researched and tested didn't work as I expected.

Comment: Ah, you want to use subpath (meuapp.com/api) instead of subdomain (api.meuapp.com). Let me try to update this answer.